# Reading Remote MP3 File's ID3 in Appcelerator,Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

I am looking for a way to read the `ID3` tags from an MP3 file on a remote server without actually downloading the file. I need to use the information extracted from ID3 for displaying what is playing in a radio application. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

`ID3` is stored at the end of the MP3 file, and it's a fixed 128 bytes size space for `ID3v1`.

You can download only the last 128 bytes of MP3 file of the remote server if server support [Range Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233)